# Finding delta between two files (Excel, Word, PDF) and appending/inserting the difference in the second file | C#

Tags: c#, pdf, delta

I am making a document management system and the the issue that I am facing here is finding the delta between the two files (say file A & B) and appending/ inserting the delta in the File B. There are a lot of ways to find delta using C# libraries or Byte-by-Byte comparison, but appending/inserting the delta is the real question here.

Note: the system will handle documents of larger file sizes

Text A: I am Kshitij.
Text B: I am = Kshitij.

The difference between the above two strings is the "=" sign which needs to be appended between "am" and "Kshitij".

The document management system will be handling Word, Excel, PDF files.

Thankyou,
Kshitij

Comment: Seems to be a very broad question when you want to handle Word, Excel and Pdf. I doubt that simply adding the delta is even going to result in a valid file.

Comment: There are a ton of tools for this (search diff tool) and some of them are open source. Also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask